# Subdomain blocked loading fonts CORS with nginx

Tags: nginx, cors, font-face, cloudflare, w3-total-cache

I'm getting this error while requesting fonts from CDN Amazon CloudFlare on my subdomain, the problems is only with Google Chrome apparently it works fine with Safari.

```
Font from origin 'http://static.wagency.co' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource 

Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wagency.co' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
Font from origin 'http://static.wagency.co' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '*.wagency.co'. Origin 'http://wagency.co' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
7Font from origin 'http://static.wagency.co' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://wagency.co' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be specific to Chrome. Saw these [tips](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/D3UclJtUU6A) in a Google Product forum about a similar issue.